# Access impl const without type parameters

Tags: rust

If I have a struct with some generics and a trait impl with a const value, is it possible to access the const before the type parameters are known?

For example, with the following,

```rust
pub trait MyTrait {
    const VALUE: u64;
}

pub struct Foo<T> {
    bar: T,
}

impl<T> MyTrait for Foo<T> {
    const VALUE: u64 = 4523452345666;
}
```

it's not possible to just do `Foo::VALUE` because the generic parameters are required, but `VALUE` from the impl will be invariant for any T.

Is there a way to access the const without type parameters?

Comment: Anything declared like that should be considered internal only, as a principle of encapsulation. If it is accessible externally, even for testing, expose it as a function, as in `fn value() -> u64 { VALUE }`. The real question if you're just testing this, or accessing it absent an implementation. If you're accessing it independent of an implementation, then it's a sign you should include that as a parameter instead, like `Foo<T,V>`, or as an external constant that's `pub`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write an impl like this...

```rs
impl<T> MyTrait for Foo<T>
```

... it means you are implementing `MyTrait` for any instance of `Foo`. So you can pass any type as `T` to get the constant. A good type for this is `()`, the unit type, but you can use literally any type.

```rs
assert_eq!(4523452345666, Foo::<()>::VALUE)
```

Comment: Using `()` is fine if you have one or two type parameters, but any more and it would get messy. Was hoping there might be a way to do it without any type parameters at all.

Comment: You could of course use something like this *outside* of the impl: `const FOO_VALUE: u64 = Foo::<()>::VALUE` and extend the number of parameters as needed.

Comment: @oorst Or do the reverse and define `const MYCONST: u64 = 4523452345666;` at the top level and then use it to set `Foo::<T>::VALUE`.

Comment: @oorst Doing anything with lots of type parameters will be messy. You can give them defaults or make a type alias if you don't want to specify them every time.